# Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, azure-devops, gradlew

I'm using **Reactnative 0.54.0** and **react-native-cli 2.0.1** along side **gradle 4.8.1**

I have created a react-native project using **create-react-native-app myProjectName**

When I created the project, it doesn't include android and ios folders, so I added them manually.

I also installed gradle using **choco** and then created a wrapper for it using **gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.8.1 --distribution-type all**

so I am developing react-native using microsoft **vsCode** and then see my application in action using **Genymotion** emulator, everything is fine

now, I want to generate the final **Signed APK** for play store, I'm using this guide provided by react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

When I want to run **gradlew assembleRelease** I get this error

```
C:\myApp\android>gradlew assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'android'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

what's wrong with assembleRelease? what should I do?

to add more info, I have to say that when I want to build this project in VSTS (TFS Online) I get this error

```
2018-07-17T16:20:14.9268702Z ##[error]Error: Not found wrapperScript: D:\a\1\s\gradlew
```

Any clue is appriciated
Thanks

**Update:**
as @philipp asked, this is the list of tasks that gradlew have listed and assembleRelease is not one one them!!!! what's the reason?

```
C:\myApp\Android>gradlew tasks

> Task :tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'android'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'android'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'android'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'android'.
dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project 'android'. [incubating]
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'android'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'android'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'android'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'android'.

To see all tasks and more detail, run gradlew tasks --all

To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

and this is myApp\android**build.gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [
    bundleInStaging: true 
]
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.8.1'
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sunkime.client"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        staging {
            keyAlias = "staging"
            storeFile = file("my-release-key.keystore")
            keyPassword = "qwert%$#@!"
            storePassword = "qwert%$#@!"
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword qwert%$#@!
                keyAlias qwert%$#@!
                keyPassword qwert%$#@!
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ".release"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}
```

I also used **gradlew clean** and no difference

Answer (score 12):

Is it specific for `assembleRelease` or is `gradlew assembleDebug` working?

Maybe try `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Posting your apps `build.gradle` could also help.

As a first task I would recommend to run `./gradlew tasks` to check if gradle is set up correctly and the task `assembleRelease` is listed.

Comment: I updated the question, and added **build.gradle** and a list of available **gradlew tasks**, assembleRelease is not listed!!!! I also used **gradlew clean** and no difference. do you have any idea, why assembleRelese is not listed?

Comment: Maybe you are running `gradlew` from the wrong directory. You can also try using the `gradlew.bat` for Windows

Comment: yes i wanna integrate it with bitrise as CI CD can anyone help on this

Answer (score 5):

You need a `settings.gradle` file into your Android folder.

Answer (score 5):

If `assembleRelease` and `assembleDebug` tasks don't working, you can try `gradlew assemble`

Comment: As of 22nd November 2019, this is actually what works! gradlew assemble

Answer (score 4):

That error can occur after upgrading versions of IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, or after Generating a new APK, you may need to refresh the IDE's cache.
It can also be due to updating the location of SDK.
Just a simple hack will do, Invalidate cache

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have finally solve this error:

You have to check, one by one each versions of your dependencies in your pubspec.yaml.
During one week I got stuck bcs my version of path_provider package wasn't the latest.

Answer (score 1):

For me works setting the ANDROID_HOME and delete file local.properties with "sdk.dir=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk". When gradle does not find the local properties It search in ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not finding the android environment variables

Run the command on the mac like this to load the variables

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I accidentally deleted app build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... does magic

Answer (score 0):

```
"createAndroidBuild" : "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease"
```

**In terminal run this script using below command**

```
yarn createAndroidBuild
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me I remove : before `assemble`
this throw error

```
./gradlew clean :assembleRelease
```

solved by

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```