# How to run an executable in a different dir when running make command in root dir?

Tags: android, react-native, makefile, terminal

Bit of a noob question but I'm building an app in react native and to make development a bit faster I'm using a make file for arbitrary commands. I need to run an executable in a sub-directory but can't get this to work while using the Makefile command.

The command works when I cd into the directory then run it but this doesn't work when I use the exact same commands for the make command and I'm sure there's a one line answer to this somewhere but I haven't been able to find it.

Doing this works

```
user@device:~/project$  cd android
user@device:~/project/android$  ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

but having it in the makefile like so doesn't

```
///////// Start of Makefile /////
apk:
    cd android/
    ./gradlew assembleRelease

///// End of file ///////

user@device:~/project$  make apk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `android/gradlew assembleRelease`?

There is [some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile#1789616) elsewhere on SO about why commands like `cd` won't work as expected in a makefile.

Comment: assembleRelease is also in the android directory and whenever I run the command I get this error ```Task 'android/assembleRelease' not found in root project```

I thought as much when I was putting ```cd``` into the Makefile that I was definitely doing something wrong but I'm stumped as to how to reference both the executable and the file I'm passing to it.

Comment: more potentially related stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397363/task-assemblerelease-not-found-in-root-project-android